# Deleting Visualization from Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I just added a large JSON object in the Visualization x-axis filters tab which sent me to this page

http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/error/url-overflow?_g=()

> Kibana limits URLs in your browser to 25000 characters for your safety.

Kibana is shutting me out. How can I delete this visualization?

Answer (score 7):

Go to **Stack Management** > **Saved Objects**.
Once you find your Visualization check the **checkbox** and select **Delete**

[Official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/managing-saved-objects.html)

Answer (score 2):

Solved this if anyone else has this problem. Kibana UI is saving the previous request somewhere (tried clearing everything) ended up going to each of the following links to reset the 'saved url'..

- http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard
- http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/timelion
- http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/visualize/new